# Creating a channel on microsoft teams with site design schema

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, json, microsoft-teams, provisioning

Is it possible to add a parameter to JSON schema (team site) to automatically create a channel In Microsoft teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using site design script.

You can check currently supported list of actions at: [Site design JSON schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Ganesh Sanap. Per my understanding, this requirement is currently not supported.